# Detecting last character deleted/backspaced in a RichEditBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, markdown, richeditbox

I need to know what the last character that has been deleted/backspaced in my RichEditBox is, as depending on what the character is, I need to trigger certain checks to be made. This is for my UWP C#/xaml Markdown app - if the last character removed is a *, then I need to check whether the removed * results in a loss of formatting. For example, if the first * in *italics* is removed then I need to change italics to not be formatted in italics.

Comment: Have you tried temporarily saving the text on each textChanged event and comparing it with the previous text change ? In other words, you can save the text of the first textchanged event and compare it with the second textchanged event to detect what part of string has changed..

Comment: That is an option I considered but thought it would be too slow needing to iterate through the string character by character, especially as I could be dealing with many paragraphs of strings, and hoped there would be a more optimised alternative from a coding and performance perspective.